# Error when adding Developer inserts (IE: Command Button)

Tags: script, vba, microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

Running Visio 2010.

I go to the Developer tab.

When I  try to insert any of the ActiveX controls (IE: Command Button), I get an error (*even after uninstalling and re-installing Visio*):

> An error (1440) occurred during the action Insert PushButton.
>   Visio is unable to insert this control.

Answer (score 1):

This error is becasue  because Visio is not a supported container for the Visio Drawing Control.  Visio Drawing Control works as another instance of  Visio program and gives some functionality of the same program and Visio and control cannot co-exist

The official online Microsoft Support says

> "Microsoft has confirmed that this is a problem in the Microsoft products"

If you simply copy  ActiveX control from any installation disk or from a network without using a Setup program, the control will never appear in the list and an error will occur because control is not registered - You must register the control before you use it.

There is however a work around given by Microsoft to register an Active X Control before adding it , follow the steps given in the link below

[Insert an ActiveX control in a drawing](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/insert-an-activex-control-in-a-drawing-HP085052825.aspx)

Comment: That makes it sound like Visio has a component that isn't supported and doesn't work with Visio...  I know it works as I've used them before (not on this computer though).  That link doesn't seem to show anything to get it to work either (unless it's indicating that I have an unregistered file, but not sure which one).